# How can search a string array contains metod without loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have an array of view model. Now I want to check that view model array to contain a word within an array.

```
 public IQueryable<CategorisedPostViewModel> GetRelatedPostbyCategories(string categories)
 {
       var ctries = categories.Split(',');
       var result = GetAllCategoriedPost().**Where(p=>p.CategoryName.Contains(ctries)).**OrderByDescending(c => c.Published);
       return result;
  }
```

How can I search that bold portions without loop?

We may assume for simplicity,

```
p.categoryName="jerry,tom,ema"
```

and

```
ctries={"Gates","jerry","Jobs","ema"}
```

I want to check if any ctries is found on p.categoryName. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if any category name is present in ctries try, [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
p.categoryName.Intersect(tries).Any()
```

Comment: You need to call Split first
`p.CategoryName.Split(',').Intersect(ctries).Any()`

Apart from that @orbit
Why not store `CategoryName` as `List` or similar.
Additionally you may use the `params` keyword for your parameter instead of relying on a correctly formatted string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Fahadsk . Is there any site to enrich these sorts of knowledge?

Comment: Hey thnx @orbit, glad that worked. well there are tons of such sites to name a few, [c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com), [codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com), [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com), [dot net tricks](http://www.dotnetcurry.com), [dot net curry](http://www.dotnetcurry.com), [video sources](https://www.pluralsight.com/) and ofcourse [google](http://www.google.com)